# need to automatically create a list of links for indexing

Tags: indexing, hyperlink, web-crawler, sitemap

I have 2,500 html files which I need to automatically add to my index page, so I can create a sitemap and my file can be crawled and indexed. Obviously I cannot add that many manually. Any idea of how to accomplish this quickly?

Thanks in advance,
Sascha

Comment: Could you add some more details? It sounds like you want to link to the 2500 pages from your index page?

Comment: Yes, that's right.  All links need to be on a search/index page.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to link to the 2500 pages from your index page. I'm assuming that all of your HTML content is located in a folder called "html-folder/".

Add the following code to a new file (e.g., "my-script.sh"), then run it using `bash my-script.sh`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
for i in html-folder/*; do
  page_path="html-folder/$i"
  page_name="$i"
  echo "<a href=\"$page_path\">$page_name</a>" >> links.html
done
```

After running the script, copy and paste the content of its output located in `links.html` into whichever page of your site where you want to list the links.

Comment: ok. But I'm not a programmer/developer,so can you please tell me how to use this script?